# execute http post with Lua

Tags: python, http, post, lua, http-headers

I have written a Python script which POSTs data to an apache webserver and the data arrives nicely in $_POST and $_FILES aray. Now I want to implement this same thing in Lua but I can't get it going yet.

My code in Python looks something like this:

```
    try:
        wakeup()
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(TIMEOUT)
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(MultipartPostHandler.MultipartPostHandler)
        host = HOST
        func = "post_img"
        url = "http://{0}{1}?f={2}&nodemac={3}&time={4}".format(host, URI, func, nodemac, timestamp)
        if os.path.isfile(filename):
            data = {"data":open(filename,"rb")}
            print "POST time "+str(time.time())
            response = opener.open(url, data, timeout=TIMEOUT)
            retval = response.read()
            if "SUCCESS" in retval:
                return 0
            else:
                print "RETVAL: "+retval
                return 99
    except Exception as e:
        print "EXCEPTION time "+str(time.time())+" - "+str(e)
        return 99
```

The Lua code I have come up with thus far:

```
#! /usr/bin/lua

http = require("socket.http")
ltn12 = require("ltn12")

http.request{
    url = "localhost/test.php?test=SEMIOS",
    method = "POST",
    headers = {
        ["Content-Type"] =  "multipart/form-data; boundary=127.0.1.1.1000.17560.1375897994.242.1",
        ["Content-Length"] = 7333
    },
    source = ltn12.source.file(io.open("test.gif")),
    sink = ltn12.sink.table(response_body)
}
print(response_body[1]) --response to request
```

but this code keeps getting me this on execution:

```
$ ./post.lua
/usr/bin/lua: ./post.lua:17: attempt to index global 'response_body' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        ./post.lua:17: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
reg@DesktopOffice:~$
```

Comment: I'm confused, are you trying to write a client side Lua script that does the same as your Python script or are you trying to write a server side Lua script that will process the data sent by your Python script?

Comment: @Paul, I need to write a Lua script that does the same as the Python script, yes.

Answer (score 1):

There are several examples of sending POST data using Lua: [from the author of luasocket](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2008-07/msg00206.html) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17372330/lua-socket-post). [This example](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2012-05/msg00568.html) works directly with files, which is very close to what you are using.

Your description of this question doesn't match the [comment you provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18090875/analyze-http-post-multipart-header-data?noredirect=1#comment26522095_18090875).