# Its possible to set fields values of a site and submit then with a Programing Language?

Tags: lua

I have this site: 
https://acad.unoesc.edu.br/academico/login.jsp

And I want to put info in the fields values and submit then, to get the next page and navigate in that site. Thats because I want to create an android app or something like that. Im using lua in first case, with luasocket(http).

I know that the input has its names, but I dont know how to set then and send then to the server. If someone can help me with this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use POST method with luasocket. See the [official documentation](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/http.html) and a detailed example in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17372330/lua-socket-post).

Since you seem to be doing authentication, you'll probably need to save the cookie value returned to you as part of the login response and then pass that cookie back to the server (otherwise your subsequent requests will fail as the server will reject those requests as non-authenticated).

Since you are sending this over https, you'll need to use [LuaSec](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~brunoos/luasec/), which provides ssl.https module as replacement for the http module that luasocket provides. You may check [my blog post](http://notebook.kulchenko.com/programming/https-ssl-calls-with-lua-and-luasec) for some example of how this can be done.

Comment: Thank you Paul. I was looking in this too: http://luaselenium.sourceforge.net/ but i think that this is obsolet :( I will take a look in that