# How to send data from a Lua Script to a Meteor app?

Tags: meteor, lua

I would like to update a Meteor Leaderboard app with data from my lua plugin for World of Warcraft.

Can Lua send POST request? If so, since Meteor uses DPP, how does Meteor handle the request?

Thanks folks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can send POST requests from Lua using luasocket. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17372330/lua-socket-post) and [luasocket http documentation](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/http.html) for details.